# Updating from 2.3.5 to 2.4.4 gives magento/framework 102.0.5 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 error

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4, composer

Magento 2.3.5

I am trying to update from Magento 2.3.5 to Magento 2.4.4-p2. The commands I executed are:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.4-p2 --no-update --use-default-magento-values
composer update
```

I am running PHP 7.4 and the error I get is: **magento/framework 102.0.5 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.30) does not satisfy that requirement.**

Switching back to PHP 7.3 gives me: **magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4-p2 requires php ~7.4.0||~8.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.33) does not satisfy that requirement.**

How would I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply one of 2 solutions below:

Solution 1: Firstly, switch to PHP 8.1, then update the composer.json file specifically the require-dev section with what is written here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4-p2/composer.json

Then remove **vendor** folder and run the following commands:

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4-p2 --no-update
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Solution2: Do the following steps:

1. STAY IN PHP 7.3 (or PHP 7.4)
2. composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
3. composer update
4. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4-p2 --no-update
6. composer update
7. CHANGE TO PHP 8.1
8. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade; bin/magento setup:di:compile; bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35306

Comment: Thanks, when does the update take place in solution 1? I cant change to 7.2 or 7.3 and run the update, it will complain about minimum PHP version 7.4.

Comment: You should do solution 1. Only do solution 2 if you have issue: "Fatal error: During inheritance of Countable:..." when running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` after doing solution 1.

Comment: Ok, but where in solution 1 would the update take place if I only replace the require-dev part? Or should I use the full composer.json in my project?

Comment: I've updated solution 1, thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try!

Comment: Have you succeeded in this upgrade? If this answer work for you, please mark it as **accepted**, it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Answer (score 2):

tldr, you should use PHP 8.1.

First of all, you shouldn't just run `composer update`. Instead, just run `composer update magento/product-community-edition`. It will update **ALL** your dependencies. If problems occur, you have no idea where they come from. Then, Magento 2.4.4 runs with PHP 8.1. You want to use the latest Version as PHP 7.4 is almost out of its lifecycle and will **die** in a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks, I ran composer update magento/product-community-edition and switched to PHP 8.1 before. This is what I got: https://pastebin.com/P8yt0QvR

Comment: Well, you have to read the output yourself. Specific dependencies are out of date and need to be updated as well. You can get an overview of what has to be updated by running `composer outdated -D`.